# Имплементация bittorrent протокола

Tags: java, tcp-ip, p2p

Заинтересовался данной темой. Впереди диплом 
( через год), выбираю тему. Однако информации мало.  В качестве языка желаю использовать java. Тема интересная, но не понятно даже с чего начать. 
    Может какие-то советы дадите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой протокол имеет под собой стандарт, изложенный в виде каких-либо спецификаций. Также обычно существуют дополнения к базовой специкации, расширяющие возможности протокола. Реализовывать их, или нет, зависит от потребностей.

Поэтому, берете спецификации:

[http://www.bittorrent.org/](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html)

Берете в качестве примера готовый API:

- [Ttorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent)
- [Vuze](https://sourceforge.net/projects/azureus/files/vuze/Vuze_5700/Vuze_5700_source.zip/download) (клиент)

И пишете.

Вроде ничего сложного, примеров в сети навалом.